# In advance search webpart, properties search not working in SharePoint2013

Tags: document-library, advanced-search

I am using SharePoint 2013 advance search webpart and i have created custom properties.search by using those properties not showing any data.

Steps which i follow is:-

1. Created site column "DocTest" & add them in my document library.
2. Add data in document library and put value in column "NewDocument"
3. start Full crawl.
4. Map there crawled property name "ows_q_TEXT_DocTest" & it is search,refine,retrieve is checked.
5. Again full crawl, after that when i search using this property it is not working.

Please suggest.

Comment: Can you update the query you have tried?

Comment: In advance search webpart. i have select property from drop down "DocTest" and new dropdown i select "contains" and in next textbox write "testnew"."testnew" is the column value that i need to fetch.

Comment: " 4.Map there crawled property name "ows_q_TEXT_DocTest" & it is search,refine,retrieve is checked.."  Do you mean you have created a managed property and mapped the crawled property ?

Comment: yes.i have already done that.

Answer (score -1):

you mapped wrong property, you should map `ows_DocTest` instead of `ows_q_TEXT_DocTest`